# Simplenews does not apply templates and does not resend

Tags: emails

I have a strange issue. Simplenews sends ok html formatted emails but it does not read the extra info I write in template. It actually doesn read them at all.

The second issue it doesn't resend no matter how much I try.

Comment: Which templates are you using? Where are they stored?

Comment: Templates are provided by the simplenews modules and they need to be copied in your theme folder.

Answer (score 2):

About You Second Issue - Here is a "dirty" solution.

- Go to phpMyAdmin and find simplenews_newsletters table[image]
- Edit that table and change **s_status** on the newsletter you want from 2 to 0.
  [image]

s_status - 2 Newsletter has been sent

s_status - 0 Newsletter has not been sent

s_status - 1 Sending Newsletter

Comment: Well I need the clean bushido way to do it :). Is this a simplenews bug?

Comment: Well I don't know if this is a bug.
That's what I'm doing to send one newsletter few times. 
Because I want to test it on several email clients.
(send test newsletter options it's not enought)
It's not very convinient way but at leaset I am sure my Newsletter is OK before sending thousands emails.

Answer (score 0):

Attention for the mailing items that may be present in the table "simplenews_mail_spool". In this table the remaining recipients are present for the mailing in status "pending".  they will be send out the next time the cron-job starts.